Trying to access the audio stream data using getUsermedia, but it is giving undefined in zoom apps sdk
We are trying to get access to the user’s audio stream using getUserMedia, to use that data, but we are not able to access it, and we are getting it as Undefined. But, it is crucial for our application to capture the speaker's real-time audio information. How can I achieve that? Is there any configuration that I can set in Zoom apps sdk configs? Or is there any API that can allow me to capture that real-time audio data of the user, or any other ways?
We have tried to get the user permission to get access to the microphone using getUsermedia, and the expected behavior is to get access to the user's microphone, use that audio stream data, and process that speech. But instead, it is showing as undefined in the Zoom apps.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
